# Can't find the workflow source code of a list or library on SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm new using SharePoint. I am having trouble with find the code or workflow structure of a list or a library. In the left menu i can see the "Workflows" button but all workflows are not there.

There is a workflow section In the "List and libraries" view showing the running workflows in these list, but when i click on one of them it just move me to its settings in the browser and  no to the structure or code that is what i'm looking for.

Is there a way to find the code or structure of my running workflows?

PD: I am working in place of the previous developer who build the entire site, however, he didn't show me anything about.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workflow was a visual studio sequential workflow deployed in the site as a feature. It was not a SharePoint Designer one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If these are workflows created using SharePoint Designer then:

- Open SharePoint Designer
- Open the site
- Click on Lists and Libraries
- Click on the list name
- There will be a heading titled "Workflows"
- Click on the workflow you are wanting to look at
- Click "Edit Workflow" to view it
- Go From there

If you are wanting to see the status of a workflow in regards to the item:

- Go to the list
- I recommend creating a personal view (so only you see it)
- You can select the fields you are interested in and each workflow should have a column in the list associated with it. Include the column in your view
- Go to your new view and you can click on the link to view the current status of the workflow

Answer (score 0):

Go to All Files > Workflows Folder. Then select the workflow you want to work with. Right Click on the "xoml" file then select "Open With" > "SharePoint Designer (open as workflow)"

Once it's opened, published it again. Then it will show up again in the Workflow tab.